# Scope of negation with 〜したくない

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, scope

In English, we can distinguish between **not wanting** to do something, and **wanting to not** do something.  It's not a distinction that we usually make, but it is possible:

```
P = "do anything"

A. "I want to not do anything."    　 WANT(NOT(P))
B. "I don't want to do anything."　   NOT(WANT(P))
```

The first sentence means `WANT(NOT(P))` *"I want to do nothing"*.

The second sentence literally means `NOT(WANT(P))` *"I lack the desire to do anything"*, but by implication it usually also means `WANT(NOT(P))` *"I want to do nothing"*.  Since this is just an implication, it's possible for it to be cancelled in certain contexts.

---

I was wondering if something similar is true of `〜したくない`.  Take a look at this sentence:

> 何もしたくない。

I think this usually means `WANT(NOT(P))` *"I want to do nothing"*.  But is it possible for it to mean `NOT(WANT(P))` *"I lack the desire to do anything"* as well?

Can 何もしたくない have either meaning?

Comment: Supplement:  **A** is definitely a negative volition, while **B** is more neutral.

Comment: I think this distinction works very well with ほしい: 何もしないでほしい vs. 何もしてほしくない. But I think that 何もしたくない would in fact more likely be "I lack the desire to do anything".

Comment: I think that negating the object (I want to not do it / それをしないことしたい) and negating the helping verb (I don't want to do it / それをしたくない) have clearly different meanings. Negating the object is just much less common. Personally, I can't explain the differences between "I want nothing. / I don't want anything / I don't something" even to myself.

Comment: @Earthling - 何もしないでほしい to my ears sounds like there's someone else who you're telling to not do anything (since -てほしい, as far as I'm aware, is only used for talking about what you want other people to do).

Comment: @Sjiveru That was my point. ほしい makes the distinction between "not wanting (so.) to" and "wanting (so.) to not" clear. For 何もしたくない, there isn't really a counterpart.

Comment: @Earthling Oh, yeah, I see there. Sorry! :P

Comment: @Earthling: I do not agree with the statement.  何もしてほしくない usually, if not always, means ∀x. WANT(you do not do x), that is, the same thing as 何もしないでほしい.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Maybe in practice, but isn't しないでほしい at least a stronger way of saying WANT(NOT(you do x))? It's conceivable that the weaker NOT(WANT(you do x)) just gets interpreted to mean WANT(NOT(you do x)), because しないでほしい would be too strong of an expression. Like you say そうでもない, because いいえ is usually to strong of an expression, but そうでもない (="not exactly like that"?) usually gets interpreted to mean "no".

Comment: @Earthling: Personally I do not feel that しないでほしい is stronger than してほしくない.  (If anything, I even feel that してほしくない is a little stronger for some reason.)  I am not sure about the distinction between meaning and interpretation here.  One may argue that logically, the literal meaning of してほしくない should be NOT(WANT(you do x)), but if so, I cannot come up with a case where it is used in this literal meaning.  So while I understand your logic, I am afraid that that logic does not match the actual usage.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Ok, thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The negative form …したくない means “WANT(NOT(…)).”  For example, 山に登りたくない means the speaker wants to avoid climbing a mountain.

To express “NOT(WANT(…)),” we have to use other constructs such as 山に登りたいのではない.

Compare the following examples.

1. 竜とは**戦いたくない**が、姫を助ける方法はほかにない。
2. 竜と**戦いたいわけではない**が、姫を助ける方法はほかにない。

In the first example, the speaker wants to avoid fighting against the dragon.  In the second example, the speaker is just saying that it is not that he/she wants to fight against the dragon.

Your notation related to P = “do anything” is ambiguous because it does not specify how the negation interacts with the quantifier implicit in word *anything*.  To avoid this, we should make the quantifier explicit.  Then 何もしたくない means ∀x. WANT(NOT(do x)), that is, the speaker wants to be free from all actions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can have either meaning. English allows a distinction due to the fact that there are two clauses involved (removing the negative, 'I want' and 'to do (some/any)thing'), so it allows negation in either clause. Japanese has a single clause, and so negation has to end up in a single location. So the distinction is determined purely contextually - 何もしたくない can be either 'I want to do nothing' or 'I don't want to do anything'. (And if you think about it, these are extremely similar, and it's more of a quirk of English grammar that you can somehow distinguish the two in English.)

If you wanted to specify the second, you might reword it as したいことがない, 'there isn't anything I want to do'.

Answer (score 0):

It’s true that 何もしたくない only has one interpretation (“I don’t want to do anything”) as other answers pointed out. But you aren’t out of options.

The reason we can’t use the second negation pattern is because we can’t put a negative marker on し followed by たい because たい cannot agglutinate onto ない.

However, we can get around this.

If we make the ない adverbial via ないで, we can put a verb of existence after it and stick the たい onto that verb. This gets around the agglutination restriction.

So:

何もしないでいたい

“I want to be doing nothing”

There is a progressive or stative aspect to this sentence so it isn’t a perfect equivalent of the English “I want to not do anything” but it conveys the idea. However, it does not work well for many verbs.

Instead of trying to express “I want not to” try expressing “I’d rather not” “I’d prefer not to” “I want to avoid”. Stuff like “〜するのはちょっと…” “〜する気分じゃない” “するのを避けたい” “〜しないでおこう” etc.